# How to know the type of blob file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Server send a blob file, it could be PDF or image file, how to know what is in blob,are that image or pdf?

Now, I just take this blob file and set content-type: application/pdf or image/jpg.

**My service:**

```
downloadPDF(fileId: string): Observable<Blob> {
  var header = new HttpHeaders();
  header.append('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
  return this._http.get(this._api.powerLoadApi.getFileLink(this.WellId, 
  fileId), {
    headers: header,
    responseType: 'blob',
  })
  .map(res => {
  return new Blob([res], { type: "application/pdf"} );
  });
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org) said use FileReader, but it has problems with other browser, I think.